# Error with AWS EB CLI after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, pip, aws

I realise that I could have easily waited for July 2020, but I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 today. I upgraded from 18.04 to 19.10 to 20.04.

Everything I've tried so far has worked fine except for AWS EB CLI. It worked fine on 18.04. Now, when I run `eb deploy --staged` I get the error, below.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/me/.local/bin/eb", line 5, in 
>       from ebcli.core.ebcore import main
>   ImportError: No module named ebcli.core.ebcore

Anyone got any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: To future users: please do NOT upgrade instances like AWS. The correct way is to create a system disk and a user disk. You connect system and user disk to create an instance. Upgrading to a higher version is done by creating a new system disk and then attach your user disk. Why? If the instance does not boot it is -dead- without a way to restore your system. If that includes data not on a backup it is gone.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT***

The original answer was to uninstall Python 3.8 then install the utils for 3.7. **DO NOT DO THIS.** While this did allow me to use EB CLI, Ubuntu 20.04 needs Python 3.8 to run it's GUI. As a result, after restarting the machine I was unable to log back into the Ubuntu GUI.

A better way to do this would be to remove Python 3.7 and reinstall it...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

Comment: but a headless server won't need GUI?

Comment: I meant the GUI of my desktop, i.e. I was unable to login to my desktop. This is an old question but I had a hard time with this, it's better to follow the suggestion made by @Rinzwind